# How to plot the elements of a matrix in {x,y,z} coordinates?

Tags: plotting, matrix, graphics3d

I have the {x,y,z} positions of a fullerene and after connecting the first neighbors with ~1.37 and 1.45 distances in the matrix B as the following

```
tol=0.01;
LIST={1.37,1.45};

Do[
  If[
   
   Abs[EuclideanDistance[DATAC60[[i]], 
       DATAC60[[j]]] - 
      LIST[[h]]] <= tol,
   
   
   B[[i, j]] = 1;
   
   ], {i, 1, Length[DATAC60]}, {j, 1, Length[DATAC60]}, {h, 1, 2}];
```

with [DATAC60](https://pastebin.com/nf818jXW)

I have tried to check the elements connecting them as the following

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[Line[Flatten[Table[
     If[B[[i, j]] == 1,
      {DATAC60[[i]], DATAC60[[j]]}, Nothing]
     , {i, 1, Length[B]}, {j, 1, Length[B]}], 2]
   ]]
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]
```

which gives crossing lines between the coordinates that gives B[[i,j]]=0, as the following.

[image]

I know that the matrix is correct, because is connecting only the neighbors stablished above so the problem must be in the way I'm ploting the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pasting my DATAC60 to make sure I copy pasted it right:

```
DATAC60= {{-3.45748,-0.359351,-0.581443},{-3.45748,0.359351,0.581443},{-3.00838,-1.74153,-0.581443},{-3.00838,-0.258779,1.8177},{-3.00838,0.258779,-1.8177},{-3.00838,1.74153,0.581443},{-2.58594,-2.32298,0.581443},{-2.58594,-1.55893,1.8177},{-2.58594,1.55893,-1.8177},{-2.58594,2.32298,-0.581443},{-2.28173,-1.97764,-1.8177},{-2.28173,-0.741377,-2.58176},{-2.28173,0.741377,2.58176},{-2.28173,1.97764,1.8177},{-1.41018,-3.17721,0.581443},{-1.41018,-1.94095,2.58176},{-1.41018,1.94095,-2.58176},{-1.41018,3.17721,-0.581443},{-1.17576,-2.78117,-1.8177},{-1.17576,-0.382026,-3.30046},{-1.17576,0.382026,3.30046},{-1.17576,2.78117,1.8177},{-0.726656,-3.3993,-0.581443},{-0.726656,-1.00016,3.30046},{-0.726656,1.00016,-3.30046},{-0.726656,3.3993,0.581443},{-0.683527,-2.94111,1.8177},{-0.683527,2.94111,-1.8177},{0.,-2.39915,-2.58176},{0.,-1.23626,-3.30046},{0.,1.23626,3.30046},{0.,2.39915,2.58176},{0.683527,-2.94111,1.8177},{0.683527,2.94111,-1.8177},{0.726656,-3.3993,-0.581443},{0.726656,-1.00016,3.30046},{0.726656,1.00016,-3.30046},{0.726656,3.3993,0.581443},{1.17576,-2.78117,-1.8177},{1.17576,-0.382026,-3.30046},{1.17576,0.382026,3.30046},{1.17576,2.78117,1.8177},{1.41018,-3.17721,0.581443},{1.41018,-1.94095,2.58176},{1.41018,1.94095,-2.58176},{1.41018,3.17721,-0.581443},{2.28173,-1.97764,-1.8177},{2.28173,-0.741377,-2.58176},{2.28173,0.741377,2.58176},{2.28173,1.97764,1.8177},{2.58594,-2.32298,0.581443},{2.58594,-1.55893,1.8177},{2.58594,1.55893,-1.8177},{2.58594,2.32298,-0.581443},{3.00838,-1.74153,-0.581443},{3.00838,-0.258779,1.8177},{3.00838,0.258779,-1.8177},{3.00838,1.74153,0.581443},{3.45748,-0.359351,-0.581443},{3.45748,0.359351,0.581443}}

LIST ={1.37, 1.45};

tol=0.01;
```

---

Your matrix `B` is correct. You can get the correct plot by changing the 2nd argument for `Flatten` from 2 to 1:

```
Show[Graphics3D[
  Line[Flatten[
    Table[If[B[[i, j]] == 1, {DATAC60[[i]], DATAC60[[j]]}, 
      Nothing], {i, 1, Length[B]}, {j, 1, Length[B]}], 1]]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDVEq.png]

---

I know it's not part of your question, but I thought I'd show an easier way to make `B` that might be a little easier to read through, and catch errors.

Our goal is to find the atoms in `DATAC60` that are separated by a distance magnitude within `tol` of an element in `LIST`:

```
    distMat = DistanceMatrix@DATAC60;
    B = Map[Min@Abs[LIST - #] <= tol &, distMat, {2}] // Boole;
```

In the code above we calculate the distance between every vertex in `DATAC60` (the default `DistanceFunction` for `DistanceMatrix` is `EuclideanDistance`).
We then make a matrix of 1s and 0s based off if the distances are within `tol` of a length in `LIST`.

To check for correctness, we then plot the vertices and edges together:

```
posLessThanTol = Position[B, 1];
lineList = Line@Table[Part[DATAC60, #] & /@ i, {i, posLessThanTol}];


Show[Graphics3D[{Thickness[4*10^-3], Blue, lineList, Red, 
   PointSize[0.02], Point[DATAC60]}], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Edit: I though I'd also show another way to make this Graphic from the {x,y,z} data without making a matrix `B` at all:

```
startEndDistance = 
  Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2, Norm[#1 - #2]} &, DATAC60, DATAC60, 1], 1];
bonds = Most /@ 
   Select[startEndDistance, 0 < Min@Abs[#[[-1]] - LIST] <= tol &];
lineList = Line[bonds];
(*use same Show[Graphics3D... commands from above to make same plot*)
```

---

Or possibly if you don't want/have to use the data in `DATAC60`:

```
ChemicalData["FullereneC60", "MoleculePlot"]
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkD7x.png]

Comment: Lol, that was easy! Thank you very much for your additional improvements and comments to the code and the problem itself. Do you think this method is faster than using Do, for instance, in a situation where I have a more complicated condition, like, lets suppose that (i,j) are at a distance "d" and also "i" and "j" are at a distance "r" from another point "u" also of the list DATAC60. Code example would be like:

Comment: Table[
If[
 (*(*I E j at distance d (1.37 and 1.45*)*)
 Abs[EuclideanDistance[DATAC60[[i]], DATAC60[[j]]] - 
    d[[o]]<= tol,
 
 (*(*u at distance r of i and j*)*)
 If[
  Abs[EuclideanDistance[DATAC60[[i]], DATAC60[[u]]] - 
      r <= tol && 
   Abs[EuclideanDistance[DATAC60[[j]], DATAC60[[u]]] - 
     r <= tol,

B[[i,j]]=Sign[Cross[Flatten[ArrayReshape[DATAC60[[k]] - DATAC60[[i]], {1, 3}]], 
   Flatten[ArrayReshape[DATAC60[[k]] - DATAC60[[j]], {1, 3}]]][[3]]]   
]
]

,{i,1,60},{j,1,60},{o,1,2}]
where d={1.37,1.45} and r=2.44 (for example)

Comment: My argument for not using `Do` loops here is from a readability perspective. I think having many nested `Do` loops can overcomplicate things, and make it hard to catch errors. To get pairs that are separated by  a distance in `LIST` and also a distance `r` from a reference point `DATAC60[[u]]` (I pick u=1 in this example) I would do something like:
$$ $$
`refPoint = DATAC60[[1]];`
$$ $$
`r = 2.44;`
$$ $$
`rFromU = Select[DATAC60, Abs[r - Norm[# - refPoint]] <= tol &]`
$$ $$
Then do same as I did before to get pairs separated by a distance in` LIST`